# Overlapping faces : how to create new faces (interception and complements) with Python API?

Tags: python, faces, bmesh

Suppose I have a mesh with two overlapping faces (in general, all vertices are different):

```
import bpy
import bmesh
if bpy.context.mode != 'OBJECT':
     bpy.ops.object.mode_set()
# Create circle #1
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(vertices=10, radius=3, 
                              location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), fill_type='NGON')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action="DESELECT")
# Create circle #2
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(vertices=10, radius=3, 
                              location=(1.0, 2.0, 0.0), fill_type='NGON')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action="DESELECT")
# Apply all transformations
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True, rotation=True, scale=True)
```

If possible, how can I create a new mesh with three faces : one face associated with the interception, and two faces representing the original faces with the interception removed.

I tried to use bmesh.utils.face_split_edgenet, but do not fully understand how to define "edgenet". At least, I can get it working. If I run

```
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(context.object.data)
bm.select_mode = {'FACE'}
bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
tmp = bmesh.utils.face_split_edgenet(bm.faces[0], bm.faces[1].edges)
```

"tmp" seems to be the same as bm.faces[0].

My goal is to assign different colors to 'area in circle #1, but not in circle #2', 'area in circle #2, but not circle #1', and 'both in circle #1 and circle #2'.

Answer (score 1):

**Bmesh script**

[image]

For the case of overlapping circles.

Define two circles on `z = 0` plane with centres and radii `c1.xy, r1` and `c2.xy, r2`.

Add them as bmesh circles, edges only no fill. Select the edges of circle 1. Circle 1 needs to be at (0, 0), edit to translate to and back if need be.

The distance between the centres is `R` the length of the  vector `N = c2 - c1`. Using the triangle with sides `R, r1, r2`. apply the  cosine rule (given we have SSS (side, side, side)  to get angle "alpha" opposite r2. rotate the `r1' length unit vector`N` by +/- alpha around Z axis to get the two points of intersection **

Using `N` as the normal and one of these points as a plane coordinate can bisect the circles, and move the cut points to their respective "perfect" circle intersection points. *Notice the operators to add emties at the intersection points, will show that they rarely fall on an edge of what is really a regular ngon*

Remove doubles.

Fill all edges on either side of and on plane to give non intersection parts.

The non selected edges on circle 1 side plus the selected edges of circle two side give the edges intersection in the middle.

Pass the bmesh contextual create operator the edges. Akin to pressing the <kbd>F</kbd> key in UI.

Assign materials 0 1 to circles and 2 to intersection.

Realign the normals.

Test script. run in object mode, first add some simple mesh at (0, 0, 0), assign it three materials, select and run script

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix
from mathutils.geometry import distance_point_to_plane as dp2p
from math import sin, cos, acos, degrees, radians, pi
bm = bmesh.new()

me = bpy.context.object.data

segments = 25
# circle 1
c1 = Vector((0, 0))
r1 = 8

bmesh.ops.create_circle(bm,
        radius=r1,
        segments=segments,
        matrix=Matrix.Translation(c1.to_3d())
        )
for e in bm.edges:
    print(e)
    e.tag = True
    e.select = True
# circle 2
c2 = Vector((4, 5))
r2 = 9

bmesh.ops.create_circle(bm,
        radius=r2,
        segments=segments,
        matrix=Matrix.Translation(c2.to_3d())
        )

N = (c2 - c1).to_3d()
R = N.length
R2 = N.length_squared

# half angles

a1 = (R2 + r2 * r2 - r1 * r1) / (2 * R * r2)
a2 = (R2 + r1 * r1 - r2 * r2) / (2 * R * r1)
a = acos(a2)
# circle 1
rot = Matrix.Rotation(a, 3, 'Z')
loc1 = r1 * (rot * N.normalized())
#bpy.ops.object.empty_add(location=loc1)

rot = Matrix.Rotation(-a, 3, 'Z')
loc2 = r1 * (rot * N.normalized())
#bpy.ops.object.empty_add(location=loc2)
# three cases

ret = bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(bm,
        plane_co=loc1, 
        plane_no=N,
        geom=bm.edges[:])

for v in ret['geom_cut']:
    if (v.co - loc1).length < (v.co - loc2).length:
        v.co = loc1
    else:
        v.co = loc2
bmesh.ops.remove_doubles(bm, verts=ret["geom_cut"], dist=0.001)

c1_geom = [e for e in bm.edges 
        if all(dp2p(v.co, loc1, N) <= 0.001 for v in e.verts)]
bmesh.ops.contextual_create(bm, geom=c1_geom)

c2_geom = [e for e in bm.edges 
        if all(dp2p(v.co, loc1, N) >= -0.001 for v in e.verts)]
bmesh.ops.contextual_create(bm, geom=c2_geom)
# intersection
all = set(bm.edges)
tagged = set(e for e in bm.edges if e.select)
untagged = all - tagged
inter = list((set(c1_geom) - tagged).union(set(c2_geom) - untagged))
for e in bm.edges:
    e.select = e in inter
ret = bmesh.ops.contextual_create(bm, geom=inter)

#recalc normals 
bmesh.ops.recalc_face_normals(bm, faces=bm.faces)
for f in bm.faces:
    f.material_index = f.index

bm.to_mesh(me)
me.update()
```

Notes:

Tagged edges seemed to be lost after remove doubles bmesh op, had to use select instead.

Perform some tests to see if circles intersect.

```
if r1 + r2 == R: # touching
    # fill both circles
    pass
elif r1 + r2 > R: # intersecting
    # do above
    pass
else:
    print("circles don't intersect")
```

As in a [previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130807/how-to-get-part-of-a-mesh-with-python-api-which-requires-breaking-down-some-fac), and this one I've used bmesh rather than operators.  See [Python performance with Blender operators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/python-performance-with-blender-operators) Your script in this question (using 9 operators) could be achieved with 3 operators add circle x 2 and join.  However I would recommend not using them at all if possible.

For non circular shapes getting tricky with solidify and boolean modifiers might get the job done.